# javascript constructor function property

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

In this program Complex.transfrom an individual function or is it a property of Complex constructor function. I have tested the code my understanding is its a separate function which is making sure that it's arguments are created by Complex constructor function.

```
function Complex(real, imaginary) {
  this.real = 0;
  this.imaginary = 0;
  this.real = (typeof real === 'undefined') ? this.real :parseFloat(real);
  this.imaginary = (typeof imaginary === 'undefined') ? this.imaginary : parseFloat(imaginary);
  this.name = "sagar";
 }
Complex.transform =function (num) {
 var complex;
 complex = (num instanceof Complex) ? num : complex;
 complex = (typeof num === 'number') ? new Complex(num, 0) : num;
 return complex;
};
function display_complex(re, im) {
 if(im === '0') return '' + re;
 if(re === 0) return '' + im + 'i';
 if(im < 0) return '' + re + im + 'i';
 return '' + re + '+' + im + 'i';
}
function complex_num_add(first, second) {
 var num1, num2;
 num1 = Complex.transform(first);
 num2 = Complex.transform(second);
 var real = num1.real + num2.real;
 var imaginary = num1.imaginary + num2.imaginary;
 return display_complex(real, imaginary);
}
 var a = new Complex(2, -7);
 var b = new Complex(4,  3);
 console.log(complex_num_add(a,b)); // 6-4i
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Complex.transform is it a separate function or it's a property of Complex constructor object?

Comment: I would call it a method of Complex.  A method is a property that is a function.

Comment: then why it's not showing when i am looping through a (a instance of Complex) object property. It's showing real, imaginary property

Comment: i mean if it is method/property of Complex. So when i am calling a.transform (a is instanceof Complex) as method passing a number as argument. It is supposed to give me a object which will be instanceof Complex right ? but instead its giving me this 
"Uncaught TypeError: a.transfrom is not a function  at <anonymous>"

Comment: Do this, then it does what you require: Complex.prototype.transform =function (num) {

Comment: yes now it's showing as i am expecting. Can you tell me why it wasnt showing before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I can't really explain why.  But here are two ways of doing things.  (Personally this is how I look at it: there are different ways of doing it.)

```
<script>
// Constructor function
function Numbers(num) {
  this.value = num;
}

// a member function.  When you define this outside of function Numbers, you need to add .prototype
Numbers.prototype.squareroot = function () {
  return Math.sqrt(this.value);
}

var a = new Numbers(5);
console.log(a.squareroot());

////  another way:

// Constructor function
function Numbers(num) {
  this.value = num;
  // member
  this.squareroot = function () {
    return Math.sqrt(this.value);
  }
}

var b = new Numbers(7);
console.log(b.squareroot());

</script>
```

Comment: yes i am familiar with these two. And these are reasonable to me. I just want to know why he/she did this way, is there any advantage ? That's why i am curious.